# ReactJS Reselect Container Re-Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reselect

I'm new to reactjs reselect, the problem is when I Perf.printWasted, it always shows "Content Single > Connect(Single Entries Index)" with only 1 instance than renders xx times

here's my current code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { shape } from 'prop-types';

import Entry from '/components/entries/Entry';

class Entries extends Component {
  static displayName = 'Single Entries Index';

  static propTypes = { entries: shape() };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.entries.size !== nextProps.entries.size) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    const { entries } = this.props;
    return (
      <ul className="entries">
        {entries.map(entry => (
          <Entry
            key={entry.get('id')}
            id={entry.get('id')}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
};

const makeGetEntries = createSelector(
  state => state.data,
  data => data.get('entries')
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    entries: makeGetEntries(state)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Entries);
```

Working solution using createSelectorCreator as suggested by @Logar

```
const createDeepEqualSelector = createSelectorCreator(
  defaultMemoize,
  isEqual
);

const makeGetEntries = createDeepEqualSelector(
  state => state.data,
  data => data.get('entries')
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { entries: makeGetEntries(state) };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Entries);
```

Comment: Your code seems correct, did you try to put a breakpoint in shouldComponentUpdate to check the props that are passed in ? Also, default selector will use shallowEquality, which won't work well with immutable data if you returned a new state in your reducer. But I don't think it's your problem there. Still, you can take a look at [Customize equalityCheck for defaultMemoize](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#customize-equalitycheck-for-defaultmemoize)

Comment: I believe there's nothing wrong with the class component itself, Perf doesn't indicate the class component re-rendered... something to do with the redux connect...

I will try your suggestion, thank you

Comment: Good JOB!!! "Customize equalityCheck for defaultMemoize" works ... thank you for helping me, it somehow works

Comment: Oh, you added it in your question. No need for an answer then ;)